# R Stacked Bar Percentage of Total

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
colour  week    value
Blue    201523  374
Blue    201524  310
Blue    201525  300
Green   201523  1951
Green   201524  2299
Green   201525  2111
Red     201523  414
Red     201524  361
Red     201525  279
```

I wish to produce a stacked plot with percentage of total value vs time grouped by colour.

The following code gives the correct plot but with absolute values rather than percentage of total (dataset saved as df):

```
  g <- ggplot(data = df)
  g <- g + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(x = Time, y = value, fill = Colour)) + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
  g <- g + labs(x = 'Timespan', y = '') + guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = FALSE))
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, vjust = -0.5, face = 'bold'), legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size = 10.5))
  g
```

Is there a way of obtaining the percentage of total within the call to ggplot? Or if not is it possible to do this using a ddply function before the ggplot call?

Comment: Where does the `percents` object (in `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)`) come from? Also, your columns are called `week` and `colour` in the data but `Time` and `Colour` in the graph code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for providing your data. You refer to a column `Time` in the `aes(...)` call, but there is no such column in your dataset. Also, you refer to a column `Colour`. These names are case sensitive, so there is no column `Colour` either. Did you run this code with this data before posting it??

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
df$pct <- df$value/ave(df$value,df$week,FUN=sum)  

ggplot(df, aes(x=week, y=pct, fill=tolower(colour))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_identity("color", guide="legend")
```

[image]

A couple of notes:

1. It is possible to use, e.g., `aes(y=value/sum(value),...)` within the call to `ggplot`, but unfortunately aggregating functions, like `sum(...)` *do not respect the implicit grouping* defined by `fill=...`. So you get the sum over all values, not just the values for a given group. If you want the latter, you have to augment the data.frame, as I did above.
2. Your use of color is tortured to say the least. Don't define colors in the dataset, give the groups semantic names based on their meaning in the data. Let `ggplot` worry about the colors. I had to use `scale_fill_identity(...)` to override ggplot's default color scheme.

Comment: Thanks! That works well. Yeah, just used colour as a dummy categorical variable, will let ggplot handle the plot colours